# Locating a web element relative to another web element using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use webbot/selenium to locate and click a button on a webpage. Problem is, the id of the element in question is an unknown integer that changes week to week. Here's what the page looks like:

[image]

The actual click buttons are around each of the "17:00", and the relevant html for one of those elements is:

```
<label tabindex="0" id="lbl_appt1566856800" for="appt1566856800"><span class="display-time">17:00</span><div class="small num-slots-available-container">11 <span id="spots-left-text">spots left</span></div></label>
```

Those id values change as dates roll forward, so I can't use `web.click('lbl_appt1566856800')`, as that would only work once. However, I noticed the div above the element I want to click contains the names of days of the week:

```
<div class="day-of-week babel-ignore">Monday</div>
```

Say I want to click the element where the day name in the div above it is "Monday". How can I locate that element to pass to selenium in a web.click manner?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: When you ask a question, you need to add a tag for the relevant programming language. You should probably review [ask] to further improve this and future questions.

Comment: @DebanjanB - updated with code.

Comment: @JeffC the question is tagged selenium.

Comment: Selenium is not a programming language... it's a library... and one exists for each programming language. Please add the relevant tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `x-path` to locate the element,

```
//div[@class='day-of-week bable-ignore' and text()='Monday']/following-sibling::label[starts-with(@id,'lbl_appt')]
```